# android: how to let js code to change the webview's size

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm developing an android application with API 19(android4.4).I have a linearLayout view nested another linearLayout view. Now I want change this linearLayout's height by js code, but it doesn't work.

active_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns="...." ...
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@id/sContainer"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
</LinearLayout>
```

java test code:

```
...
private LinearLayout webViewContainer;
...
private void initView(){
    LinearLayout container=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.sContainer);
    //add a child linearLayout
    webViewContainer=new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,200);
    webViewContainer.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    //add a child webview in this linearlayout
    WebView webview=(WebView)new WebView(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams webParams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    webview.setLayoutParams(webParams);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsInteraction(), "bridge");
    webView.loadUrl("http://xxxx/index.html");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
            view.loadUrl("javascript:callHtml('show')");
        }
    });
    webViewContainer.addView(webview);
    container.addView(webViewContainer);
}


class JsInteraction{
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void expand(){
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=webViewContainer.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = 500;
        webViewContainer.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        Log.v("height", layoutParams.height+"");    
    }
}
```

index.html js code

```
<script>
function callHtml(method){
    case 'show':
        setTimeout(function(){
            bridge.expand();//call app to expand after 5s
        },5000);
        break;
}
</script>
```

log shows that layoutParams.height has changed to 500, but nothing happens in my emulator, something I make wrong?
In addition, if i click a button to change the layoutParams's height, it works.

Comment: May I know the reason for this **I'm developing an android application with API 24(android4.4)**? Why you are not using latest SDK and tools?

Comment: i just test some function, it doesn't work at API 19 too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue, just change JsInteraction code to below:

```
class JsInteraction{
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void expand(final int height){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                //change size here
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's "probably" because you haven't called [`requestLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#requestLayout()) which is needed after you make layout changes (the view's layout gets invalidated)

> Call this when something has changed which has invalidated the layout of this view. This will schedule a layout pass of the view tree. This should not be called while the view hierarchy is currently in a layout pass (isInLayout(). If layout is happening, the request may be honored at the end of the current layout pass (and then layout will run again) or after the current frame is drawn and the next layout occurs.

So, after changing the height, you should call `requestLayout`...

```
linearLayout.requestLayout();
```

Comment: I add this code ,it doesn't work too. It seems that if user interaction with app , it works, but if the code initiates the change size action , it doesn't work.